# DriveImage XML 2008 R2 Task Schedule

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to create a scheduled task on two different Windows 2008 R2 Servers that will use Driveimage XML by Runtime Software to create a disk image. The tasks are scheduling fine and running at proper times and after observing the running processes even the dixml.exe shows up in the processes section of the servers task manager under the user account that is specified.

The login used to run the task has administrator credentials as well as the GPO sets to allow admin to elevate an application without prompt.

I've tried writing a batch file for the program and running it which is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe" /bC /s /c1 
/v /t"X:\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%~0,3%"
```

I broke up the above script into two lines of code for easy reading.

This script when manually run either from the cmd or double clicking will properly start the process of the backup. However, when attached as a file to the task scheduler the event 'starts' but the program itself does not begin a back-up.

I've tried converting the batch file into this action:

```
Start a program: dixml.exe
Arguments: /bC /s /c1 /v /t"X:\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%~0,3%"
Start in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML
```

According to MS in the 2008 R2 does not recoginze trailing slashes or quotations in their task scheduler so you leave them out.

The second method has the same effect of running the task, the program shows in the process tree and corresponds with the vent viewers PID code, but the back-ups are not made.

Anyone have experience with this perplexing issue?